# Console.log does nothing in console on Firefox

Tags: console.log

I found several threads about `console.log` not working on certain browsers couple years ago, I guess the issue should be solved today. Yet the following code doesn't display anything in Firebug's "console" tab (FF 43.04):

```
if (window.console) console.log( 'changed' );
```

Any idea why?

EDIT: no output, no error. This code was added inside `.on( 'change', 'input:radio', function() { });` which fires when `$( 'input[value="whatever"]' ).change();` runs.

Comment: Why wouldn't you type `console.log('changed');` without your if clause?

Comment: No output at all? No errors?

Comment: Works fine here. How are you executing this code?

Comment: Thanks I added further details in my question

Comment: @drake035 Have you checked that your event is working at all? What if you switch it to `alert('changed')`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating a file like a.html and placing it in your local IIS at c:\inetpub\wwwroot with contents:

```
<script>
if (window.console) console.log( 'changed' );
</script>
```

Then open debugger tools with CTRL+SHIFT+I, select console tab and then JS table. Open url http://localhost/a.html and it should work.

[Firefox with console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAi84.png)